# Edit Magento go invoice pdf

Tags: invoice, magento-go

I am working on Magento Go ver 1.0.0.37v. What am I trying to is that I want to edit the invoice pdf. I searched on google I found this [link](http://go.magento.com/support/kb/entry/name/custom-pdf-templates/).

According to this doc there should be an option "template" under system but I am not able to find it. So does any one know why am able to see that menu. Is this because of version or my plan that i have opted.

Comment: did you open a support ticket with Magento about that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about magento-go which is closed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I signed up for the most basic Magento Go account and saw the following menu

[image]

If you're not seeing that in your system, it's possible the Magento Go store owner has locked you out of that menu item via the `System->Permissions` menu items.  If you're the store owner and not seeing that menu, it's a Magento Go bug and you should contact support.